# Edison Ubilinux Flash Error "Cannot allocate memory of size 1610612736"

Tags: linux, intel-edison

When flashing command prompt states restarting Edison. Then when it restarts the command prompt disappears quickly and nothing new is flashed on Edison board and message stating to wait 5 mins does not appear and this message appears in flash txt.

"Cannot allocate memory of size 1610612736"

It's a DFU-Util meaning it couldn't allocate enough heap

Comment: I moved the discussion to meta. [Here](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/when-do-we-consider-questions-about-electronics-aimed-at-iot-use-cases-on-topic)

Answer (score 5):

- Right click on Computer and open Properties.
- Select Advanced System Properties
- Click Advanced tab
- Under Performance, click Settings
- Under Performance Options, click Advanced tab
- Here under Virtual memory pane, select Change
- Uncheck Automatically manage paging file size for all drives
- Highlight your system drive
- Select Custom size
- Change the Initial size value and the Maximum size value to a higher value
- (I Recommend 3500 in first box then 8000 in second)
- Click Set
- Finally Click Apply/OK all the way.

Then restart and try again! Good Luck!